# Training courses in geostatistics and spatial modelling

Tags: spatial-statistics, training

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are sources for current geo-statistical analysis classes/events: open or proprietary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/what-are-sources-for-current-geo-statistical-analysis-classes-events-open-or-pr)

Does anyone know of or have been on any training courses that specifically train in geostatistics or spatial modelling techniques with reference to the mapping (ArcGIS) world?  E.g. Kriging, interpolation etc..